# there was an error opening this document the file is damaged and cannot be repaired Error using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, .net-3.5

I am using following code in c# to export a string in PDF file.

```
  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            double TotalUTI = 0;
            displayHeader(ds.Tables[0], ref sb, ref TotalUTI);
            for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
               displayBody(ds.Tables[i], ref sb);
            }
            FooterDisplay(ds.Tables[0], ref sb, TotalUTI);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FundingSheet.pdf");
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

The displayheader(), displaybody() and displayfooter() are the methods to build a string which create a whole HTML form.
But somehow i am getting the error as file is damaged and can not be repaired.

Comment: There are a few problems with your code, but removing `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` should get you started. It's not needed, since you already have `PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);` a few lines above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set two tables parallelly in itextsharp document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888772/how-to-set-two-tables-parallelly-in-itextsharp-document) - the title is misleading, the op of that question essentially made the same mistakes as the op here.